# OpenMPI PMIX error: BAD-PARAM in file pmix_esh.c occured in MPI_Init

Tags: gcc, fortran, mpi, gfortran, openmpi

I am running a Fortran code using `gfortran` (version 6.3.0) compiler and `OpenMPI` (version 3.0.0), on a Ubuntu 17.04 system.

Typing `make clean` and `make` seems working ok. But once I type `make run` in the terminal, I got the following message:

```
[woodpecker-Aspire-TC-705:17583] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file dstore/pmix_esh.c at line 1005
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[woodpecker-Aspire-TC-705:17583] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed 
completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not 
able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!

-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[woodpecker-Aspire-TC-705:17586] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed 
completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not 
able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus 
causing the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

 Process name: [[53958,1],0]
 Exit code:    1
```

I saw similar discussions on Github https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/2897 without understanding how to resolve the issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: how did you configure Open MPI ? did you install it in an empty directory ? otherwise, try `rm -rf /.../lib/openmpi /.../lib/pmix` and `make install` again. also, how did you start your application (`mpirun` command line ? singleton mode ?)

Comment: Pleease try the same with a small Hello World program. Does it ccause the same problem? If not, show us the relevant code. If yes, tell us all details you can find about your OpenMPI installation.

Comment: To @VladimirF, I tried an "Hello world" version. With `USE MPI` in the heading, once I call MPI subroutines, the same error message arises. To @Gilles Gouaillardet, the mpirun line is "mpirun -np 8 ./output.out", so I guess it's not singleton mode you mentioned? Thanks!

Comment: Please tell us the details about your MPI installations we asked about. It is.necessary. We nees to know how it was.configured and whether you compiled it from source yourself. Please tell us what `head config.log` in the compilation directory says. Did you install to an empty directory? Please do not just answer one question, check all the details @GillesGouaillardet asked about and answer all of them.